# How to inherit "BaseServicces" or "IHostedServices" in console app

Tags: c#

So, I'm working on a console application using dotnet new console -o  and I'm trying to either inherit from either the "BaseServices" or the "IHostedServices"(So I have more control how the application stops and when it shound'nt), and a few days ago I came across something that said you need to do dotnet new worker --name . Is there any other way to inherit from those classes or do you need to do the new CLI command.

Comment: Is this about c# or using dotnet cli? Because you can do this without cli you need only one cs file and maybe simple project file to easier compile.. both can be written in notepad

Comment: There is no inheritance going there, worker template is basically a generic hosting with hosted service - see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host)

Comment: Are you trying to use methods declared on the IHostedServices? Like StartAsync(CancellationToken) or StopAsync(CancellationToken)? If so you need to bring in the service to the file you are working on and declare it in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying for example to use the StartAsync and StopAsync that are part of the IHOSTEDSERVICES

Example

Hope this helps

```
public class IHostedService1 : IHostedService { 
  Public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken  cancellationToken) { 
    Console.WriteLine("1"); 
  return Task.CompletedTask; 
  } 

  Public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) { 
    Console.WriteLine("exit 1"); 
  return Task.CompletedTask; 
  } 
}
```

And in the startup file you would add it like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHostedService<IHostedService1>();
}
```